# Does a magnetic field decrease or increase entropy?

Tags: entropy, classical-electrodynamics

My question is just the title:

Does a magnetic field decrease or increase the entropy of a system? For example if we apply a magnetic filed to a substance, is the entropy decreased or increased?

Comment: My uneducated guess is that since a magnetizable substance will align its particles partly along a certain direction, the entropy will decrease. I would like to hear a more thorough analysis of this effect though, if there is one.

Comment: When one grows a crystal from a liquid, the crystal has low entropy, the closed system "liquid+crystal" has increased entropy. So a magnetic field could be used to create a subsystem with reduced entropy, but the whole, closed system  "magnet, its power supply and the substance" will have higher entropy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many materials contain microscopic paramagnetic moments which are free to randomly orient themselves in zero magnetic field. If you apply a magnetic field, then the magnetic moments are able to lower their energy by entering a lower entropy state where they are magnetized.

In such a material the entropy tends to decrease as magnetic field increase, at least when it is able to give away entropy to its environment. (If not able, the magnetic moments will get hot instead.)

This effect is important in [magnetic refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration) because the reverse is also true: a paramagnetic material tends to absorb entropy as the field is decreased.

Thermodynamically we find that (this is an example of a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations); imagine replacing pressure with $M$ and volume with $B$):
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial B}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_B
$$
What you can see is that for entropy to change, a material needs to have a temperature-dependent magnetic moment in fixed field. This is definitely the case for paramagnetic moments which have $\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_B$ negative.

There are however some special cases where $\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_B$ is instead positive. A good example is a superconductor where decreasing temperature turns on the Meissner effect which opposes the magnetic field. In such materials we have instead that entropy increases when magnetic field is turned on.

Comment: One super-important exception: in the most naive model of a paramagnet, there is a "negative temperature" regime where the paramagnet's desire to minimize its energy and maximize its entropy are both aligned interests; such an object can be categorized as "hotter than any positive temperature". In this regime, increasing $B$ will *increase* $S$, not decrease it (which is what *makes* it negative-temperature, after all).